# Origin of saying 'Thank Buddha it's Tuesday'

Tags: popular-refrains

What is the origin of the saying 'Thank Buddha it's Tuesday.'?

Comment: Who uses this phrase?

Comment: A not very funny play on "Thank God it's Friday", I suppose.

Comment: @John Harris, out of curiosity, where have you heard it?

Answer (score 2):

As @Juhasz suggests, it certainly sounds like a play on *Thank God it's Friday*. I don't doubt that for a moment. But the OP's impression that this is a commonly used saying made me want to find out more about it.

*Thank God it's Friday*, as most of us know, is an expression used by Western and other English speakers to express relief at the arrival of the weekend ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thank_God_It%27s_Friday)). It's commonly abbreviated as *TGIF*.

As I expected, my search for *Thank Buddha it's Tuesday* turned up multiple references to *Thank Buddha it's Friday*. Here are examples:

- [Hsi Fang Temple](http://hsifangtemple.org/en/thanks-budda/): a Friday evening event at a Buddhist Temple in San Diego (also on [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/events/san-diego-buddhist-assoc-%E4%BD%9B%E5%85%89%E5%B1%B1%E8%A5%BF%E6%96%B9%E5%AF%BA/thanks-buddha-its-friday/2078691529020266/))
- [Buddha's Light International Association](https://www.sfyad.org/events/thank-buddha-its-friday-online-book-club-4): a Friday online book club
- [Solid Threads Clothing](https://solidthreads.com/products/thank-buddha-its-friday-t-shirt): a T-shirt with the phrase, and a description that reads, "Sometimes you just want to thank someone other than God for the best day of the week.  We thought Buddha seemed like a good guy to thank.."

Like *Thank God it's Friday*, *Thank Buddha it's Friday* has an abbreviation: *TBIF*. This abbreviation seems to have become part of internet slang ([AcronymsandSlang.com](http://acronymsandslang.com/definition/1082664/TBIF-meaning.html) and [AllAcronyms.com](https://www.allacronyms.com/TBIF/Thank_Buddha_It%27s_Friday)).

Only one reference specifically to *Thank Buddha it's Tuesday* turned up in my search: a reference to an English-language site offering a series of meditation sessions scheduled on Tuesdays in April of 2017 on the Spanish Island of Ibiza ([Rebeca Castella](http://www.rebecacastella.com/en/programs/ibiza/thank-buddha-its-tuesday/)).

To sum all that up, *Thank Buddha it's Friday* seems to be a pretty commonly used expression, and appears to be a well-meaning, humorous play on *Thank God it's Friday*. Someone using *Thank Buddha it's Tuesday* is likely counting on sufficient use of *Thank Buddha it's Friday* to make this expression strike a chord and probably intends to attract people interested in Buddhism or Buddhism-inspired activities like yoga or meditation by using light-hearted humor.

Comment: It is not obvious that *Thank Buddha it's Friday* is intended to be humorous; perhaps it was meant to simply adapt *TGIF* to a religion that does not postulate a personal god. If it is intended to be humorous, it is, as Juhasz points out, not very successful. *Thank Buddha it's Tuesday* **could** be intended to express a more profound idea that acceptance of Buddhism can make one indifferent to the differences between weekdays to weekends, but that is not its established meaning - as this answer makes clear, it has no established meaning.